# Find/Replace through all files on the root directory through SSH

Tags: security, bash, shell, unix, ssh

I just noticed that my website got hacked and all the .php files have a base64 encode string on line 1. The string is the same across every file so...

**How can I search my entire root directory and remove this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '/string-to-remove/{1d;}' '{}' \;
```

edit:

- added `-name '*.php'` to restrict this to .php files.
- added sed matching directive

Comment: Might want to add a `-name` in there too, to limit to php

Comment: where '1d' is the string I want to remove?

Comment: I'd recommend adding a `-name '*.php'` to the `find` command to not remove all sorts of other things. And instead of deleting the first line indiscriminately in the `sed` command, search for the particular string (OP says it's the same across every file) and remove only if a match is found. (Even better, only match against the 1st line of every file).

Comment: @Dan for `sed`, `1d` is saying telling it to delete the first line.  you can do things like `4,6d` to delete lines 4 through 6 or `$d` to delete the last line.

Comment: hmm, im having some trouble. Here's what I have

`find /home/dangold10 -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '<?php "php code is here. Double quotes do exist in the line i want removed" ?>{1d;}' '{}' \;`

Comment: the `string-to-remove` is a regex that you'll use to match against the first line, as a precaution.  it should only be enough to uniquely distinguish the 'bad' line from all of the other first lines in your *.php files.  it doesn't have to be the full first line.